# Socket.io sequence of calls unclear

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Iḿ doing a socket.io, Node project and I dont understand the squence of calling the functions.
I have the following code for the server:

```
//Socket setup
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var c= [];

//functions
function y(clientid){
    console.log('Show clients: '+c)
}

var x = function(socketid, fn) {
    var customid = y(socketid)
    console.log('x is calling');
    fn(customid);
};


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('User connected with %s', socket.id);

    socket.on('storeClientInfo', function (data) {
        console.log('Thought this would be the first call')
        //clients.push here
    });
    
    
    x(socket.id, function(socketid, ) {
        socket.emit('random', {
            test1: 'test1',
            test2: 'test1'
        });

    });
});
```

My code for the client is:

```
var socket = io();

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            socket.emit('storeClientInfo', { customId:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1 )});
        });

        socket.on('random', function (message) {
              //display message here
        });
```

My console log outputs:

```
User connected with MH0WD_zNzVOzi_6oABAB
Show clients: 
x is calling
Thought this would be the first call
```

Now my question is: Why at first the method gets called an not the socket.on('storeClientInfo')?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the sequence of events in time:

1. Your socket setup code runs and registers the `io.on('connection', ...)` event handler.
2. Your client attempts a connection and registers event handlers for both the `connect` and `random` events on that socket.  Note: This socket is NOT yet connected.  It's in the process of trying to connect.
3. The server receives the connection and the `connection` event on the server is called.
4. You output the result of `console.log('User connected with %s', socket.id);` and see `User connected with MH0WD_zNzVOzi_6oABAB` in the console.
5. You then register the `socket.on('storeClientInfo', ...)` event handler for that newly connected socket.
6. You then call `x(socket.id, ...)` which then calls `y(...)` which outputs `Show clients:` .
7. `y()` finishes executing and then `x()` outputs `x is calling`.
8. At this point the server-side connection logic is done.
9. The client then receives it's `connect` event and you send a message to the server with `socket.emit('storeClientInfo', ...)`.
10. Your server receives the `storeClientInfo` event and the `socket.on('storeClientInfo', ...)` event handler runs and you output `Thought this would be the first call`.

---

Perhaps the part you didn't know about is that in the client, this code:

```
var socket = io();
```

is asynchronous.  This just starts the process of connecting.  The socket is not connected yet when this returns.  There is a socket.io `socket` object available for you to register event handlers on, but it is not yet connected to the server.
That's why you have to register an event handler for the `connect` event to see when it actually completes the connection.